# How to amend an ArrayList with data sent between two fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an array list which is responsible for storing a collection of exercises names as 'Workouts'. The array list, situated in Fragment A, gets its data from an argument sent through a Bundle in Fragment B.

When a user wants to pick an exercise they press an option of 2 buttons on Fragment A which populates different exercises names on Fragment B. When an exercise is picked in Fragment B then the exercise name is sent back to Fragment A.

The argument taken from Fragment B is meant to be appended to the array list in Fragment A, however every time the Fragment A is reloaded the array list is refreshed therefore removing the previous exercise that was saved. I know this is because `new ArrayList<String>()` is defined in the onCreateView of Fragment A but is there a way that it can only be created once? (on Fragment A's initial creation rather than every transition between Fragment B & A).

**OnCreateView of Fragment A:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor, container, false);

        //BUTTON SETUP
        final Button addUpButton  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddUpper);
        addUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newExe(addUpButton);
            }
        });

        final Button addLowButton  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddLower);
        addLowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newExe(addLowButton);
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstWorkout);

        //CREATE AN ARRAY LIST TO AMMEND WITH EXERCISES
        workoutSave = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (getArguments() == null) {
            return view;
        }
        else{
            getValue= getArguments().getString("Movement");
            workoutSave.add(getValue);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.item_list, R.id.txtWorkout, workoutSave);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

**How Fragment A is reloaded from Fragment B when list item is pressed:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String exercise = lstExe.get(position);
                Fragment myFragment = new EditorFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Movement", exercise);
                myFragment.setArguments(args);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout,myFragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what do you mean by "every time fragment A is reloaded"?

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar every time Fragment A replaces the frame layout from Fragment B and the view is "reloaded" with the previous layout. An example timeline of this flow  would be shown as `appStart --(CREATE)--> fragment A` , `fragment A --(LOAD)--> fragment B` , `fragment B --(RELOAD)--> fragment `

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar i have updated the post showing how the data is transferred between the two Fragments when the new layout has been "reloaded"

Comment: do you want to keep it through the lifecycle of your app or just when returning to the fragment? check if `onSavedInstanceState` can help.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar i would like the (CREATE) to happen only once however the (LOAD) and (RELOAD) may occur several times, with data being transferred through each (RELOAD) and appended to the array list in Fragment A

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar so to answer your question i would like to keep it through the lifecycle of the app until i terminate Fragment A manually